# Use custom delimiters in the current Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I use Twig to generate LaTeX documents. Twig's default delimiter syntax clashes badly with LaTeX's curly braces. Simply escaping LaTeX is no option as it makes the code completely unreadable. I know I can [define custom delimiters globally](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax), but I don't want to rewrite all of my HTML templates to use the new syntax.

I also know about [verbatim sections](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) but those make the code truly ugly:

```
\ihead{
{% endverbatim %}
{{ title }}
{% verbatim %}
}
```

Is there a way I can change the syntax *for just the current template or a set of templates*, something like:

```
{% set_delimiters({
    'tag_comment'  : ['<%#', '%>'],
    'tag_block'    : ['<%' , '%>'],
    'tag_variable' : ['<%=', '%>'],
    'interpolation': ['#<' , '>']
}) %}
```

Comment: There is a way, definitely. As last resort you may just overwrite/extend some things. Would like to give a better answer but unfortunately I've not so much expertise with `Twig` in special. Can only say: "It will work"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, it's not recommanded to use this feature [Customizing the Syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax)

BTW here's a quick and easy example to explain how to use custom delimiters in symfony:

**service.yml**

```
services:
    templating_lexer:
        public: true
        parent: templating.engine.twig
        class:  Acme\YourBundle\Twig\TwigLexerEngine
```

**TwigLexerEngine**

```
namespace Acme\YourBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;

class TwigLexerEngine extends TwigEngine
{
    public function setTwigLexer($lexer)
    {
         $this->environment->setLexer($lexer);

         return $this;
    }
}
```

**Your controller**

```
public function yourAction()
{
    $lexer = new \Twig_Lexer($this->get('twig'), array(
        'tag_comment'  => array('{*', '*}'),
        'tag_block'    => array('{', '}'),
        'tag_variable' => array('{$', '}'),
    ));

    $templating = $this->get('templating_lexer');
    $templating->setTwigLexer($lexer);

    return $templating->renderResponse('YourBundle::template.html.twig');
}
```