# How to include mix of interpreted and uninterpreted text in twig template

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, mustache

I'm using twig along with the Symfony2 framework.
I'm also using mustache templates embedded in the HTML for client side rendering (in javascript).

In my Symfony project I'm building twig templates with bricks of other twig templates. This is made easy with the "include" functionality.

When I want to include some mustache templates to the twig template I can use the the "source" functionality that is a kind of equivalent of the "verbatim" functionality for the whole template.

My problem occurs when I want to ***mix interpreted and uninterpreted text***.

For instance I want a path to be interpreted but I don't want the mustache markups to be interpreted.

**my_twig_template.html.twig**

```
<body> 
    blablabla
    {{ source('my_mixed_template.html.twig') }}
</body>
```

**my_mixed_template.html.twig**

```
<script type="x-tmpl-mustache" id="my-mixed-template">

    {{ path('path_to_be_interpreted_by_twig') }}

    {{mustache_var_not_to_be_interpreted_by_twig}}    

</script>
```

Any clue how to do this?

Comment: You should be able to change [twig lexer settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794497/use-custom-delimiters-in-the-current-twig-template)

Comment: @DarkBee: I'm not very found of this "solution"... . Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can also change the delimiters of Mustache like described in the documentation: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#set-delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by myself.

In the main twig template:

```
{% include 'my_mustache_template.html.twig' %}
```

In the twig template embedding a mustache template:

```
{% verbatim %}
    <script type="x-tmpl-mustache" id="my-id">
        {{ mustache_variable }}
        {% endverbatim %} {{ twig_variable }} {% verbatim %}
        {{ another_mustache_variable }}
    </script>
{% endverbatim %}
```

The {% endverbatim %} {{ twig_variable }} {% verbatim %} sequence allows the twig interpreter to replace the twig variable by its actual value.