# Replace a special character from a html with another character not working

Tags: php, regex, twig

Hi I have a template : fetched from db I need to sent it as email to customer. So I want to replace [[]] with {{}} so that twig can replace actual variable with values easily.

```
<p>Dear [[LOCATION_OWNER]],</p>\n
\n
<p><br />\n
We are exited [[LOCATION]]</p>\n
\n
<p>It is very early stages at the moment, and it may not get picked     fromour selection, but we wanted to let you know.</p>\n
\n
<p>Here my contents</p>\n
\n
<p>Best wishes,</p>\n
\n
<p>[[CUSTOMER]]</p>
```

I am trying this following ways:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/[[]]/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '{{}}';
$output = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $getTemplates->getEmailTemplate());
```

but its not replacing the [[]] with {{}}. what I am missing in this please help. I am using twig as template

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an imperfect method, but it is simple and is suitable in most cases:

```
$regex = '/(\[\[)(.+?)(\]\])/';
$text  = '[[xxx]] [[yyy]] [[zzz]]';
echo preg_replace($reg, '{{$2}}', $str); // {{xxx}} {{yyy}} {{zzz}}
```

But if templates don't use a Twig syntax, may be adapt the Twig? You can [change](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax) the tag variable delimiters. See also [detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21811150/1220930) for the Symfony environment.