# How to disable comments on "twig"?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, twig, handlebars.js

1. I use `gulp-twig` and `handlebars.js` in the project
2. I work in the file index.twig
3. In twig the symbol `#`  means a comment.

For the handlebars template, I need to use the `{{#each}}` line
But `twig` perceives it as a comment, how to be?

I'm sorry for bad English

Comment: Why do you want twig and handlebars at the same time? They're for the same thing.

Comment: @Fuser97381 A javascript template engine and a PHP template engine can co-exist and satisfy different needs. Twig is ideal for anything using the data coming from the server that is pre-rendered, while an AJAX HTML template will require a javascript renderer.

Comment: To be clear, you are using [this version](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js)?

Comment: @Just a student https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-twig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/verbatim.html) like this:

```
{% verbatim %}
    ....
    {{#each}}
    ....
{% endverbatim %}
```

The code which is between the verbatim tags is not parse.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the delimiters of twig, as explained in this question:

[Use custom delimiters in the current Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794497/use-custom-delimiters-in-the-current-twig-template)

Alas, handlebars seems to not let you customize the delimiters. Keep in mind the note from the symfony guys concerning custom delimiters:

> Twig allows some syntax customization for the block delimiters. It's not recommended to use this feature as templates will be tied with your custom syntax. But for specific projects, it can make sense to change the defaults.
>
> http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax

Comment: does not work, I do not have a php version, but node.js (gulp package)  :(