# jQuery QueryBuilder doT.js template syntax inside twig file

Tags: twig, dot.js, jquery-query-builder

I try to rewrite the rule template like this:

```
$(queryBuilderId).queryBuilder({
         templates: {
                rule: '\
                    <div id="{{= it.rule_id }}" class="rule-container"> \
                          <div class="rule-header"> \
                                <div class="btn-group pull-right rule-actions"> \
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-delete="rule"> \
                                         <i class="{{= it.icons.remove_rule }}"></i> {{= it.translate("delete_rule") }} \
                                     </button> \
                               </div> \
                         </div> \
                         {{? it.settings.display_errors }} \
                            <div class="error-container"><i class="{{= it.icons.error }}"></i></div> \
                         {{?}} \
                         <div class="rule-filter-container"></div> \
                         <div class="rule-operator-container"></div> \
                         <div class="rule-value-container"></div> \
                   </div>'
        }
})
```

I have included the doT.js in my header, but twig throws me this error:
`Unexpected token "operator" of value "=".`

Does somebody knows how I can use doT.js template syntax inside my twig file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use custom delimiters in the current Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794497/use-custom-delimiters-in-the-current-twig-template)

Comment: @DarkBee I am a front-end dev how can I write a controller to use dot.js in twig?

Comment: As seen in the linked answer you need to change the delimeters `twig` uses (or the ones from dot.js but i don't if that is possible). The relevant section in the linked answer can be found under `your controller`. Ask your backend to change the delimeters to your choice