# how can I shim unknown tags with registerUndefinedTokenParserCallback()?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am extending some code from an OSS project to cover a new use case and need to parse twig files to extract data from them.

In order to correctly parse twig templates, the `Environment` class needs to be configured so that unknown tags are ignored, but the internal nodes parsed.

Twig provides `registerUndefinedTokenParserCallback()`, but while I had code available to shim functions and filters (via `registerUndefinedFilterCallback()` and `registerUndefinedFunctionCallback()`) I could not make the Token Parser work.

```php
class TwigUtils
{
    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Return a factory to shim any symbols that can't be resolved in the Twig template being parsed.
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return \Closure
     */
    public static function undefinedSymbolHandler(string $type) {
        return function ($name) use ($type) {
            return new $type($name);
        };
    }
}
```

```php
...
$loader = new FilesystemLoader();
$env = new Environment($loader);

$env->registerUndefinedFilterCallback(TwigUtils::undefinedSymbolHandler(TwigFilter::class));
$env->registerUndefinedFunctionCallback(TwigUtils::undefinedSymbolHandler(TwigFunction::class));
$env->registerUndefinedTokenParserCallback(TwigUtils::undefinedSymbolHandler(Token::class));
```

I am not very familiar with PHP and Twig development, and tried passing either the `Token` class or the `TokenParser` class, without success.

How can I shim unknown tags? My goal is to have the parser ignore unknown tags, but still process nested nodes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change the [lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794497/use-custom-delimiters-in-the-current-twig-template)  of twig?

Comment: @DarkBee changing the lexer solves a different problem. I need to process but ignore valid tags, not invalid delimiters